# Using wild cards in GRASS to remove files

Tags: grass-gis, wildcard

I have a bunch of files on a GRASS location, all named *temp_something*, that I want to delete. I tried to use the *g.remove* tool using the *multiple* option and typing *temp** in, but it doesn't work out, and a *character * not allowed* error is reported.

Am I doing something wrong or is there just no way GRASS works with wildcards?

Comment: Have you tried something like `g.mremove -f rast=temp*` ?

Comment: I'm afraid <i>g.mremove</i> has been deprecated and is now an option of the standard _g.remove_ command as I get **: command not found** from the command line.

Comment: Right, this is a GRASS 6.4.3. command. Glad you found the solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had success by using **g.remove -f type=vector pattern="temp*"**

It turns out, when intending to remove multiple files based on their names and making use of wildcards, one uses the **pattern** parameter and not the **name**.

Comment: The **name** option can be used with multiple names when you already know the names of maps to remove: `... name=raster1,raster2,raster3 ...`

Comment: Indeed.  Now I use name when the files names' have little in common, as in: DEM_azores; raster_hillshade; pop_ilhas.